# Input String was not in the correct format sometimes

Tags: vb.net, csv

I found a snippet of code on the internet that I have adopted for my need of writing a datareader connection to a .csv file. The database files that I am pulling range from 10 columns, all the way up to 200 columns. On some queries, I get a the Input String was not in the correct format; which I believe is occurring in the conversion portion of my code that changes the reader value to a string. Attached is the code.

```
Dim sw As New StreamWriter(filename)
Try
    Using Conn As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(ConnStr)
        Using Cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(query, Conn)
            Conn.Open()
            Using dr As Odbc.OdbcDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Dim fields As Integer = dr.FieldCount - 1
                While dr.Read()
                    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    While i <= fields
                        If i <> fields Then
                            sep = ","
                        Else
                            sep = ""
                        End If
                            sb.Append(dr(i) + sep)
                            i += 1
                    End While
                    sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
        sw.Close()
        sw.Dispose()
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Using
```

Comment: Have you got any more information about where the error is being thrown - a stack trace etc.  I can't see anything obvious in your code that would be throwing that error.

Comment: Please specify the line that throws the exception

Comment: I am not sure that code can result in that error. That error is usually the result of trying to parse something from string to another type - you are doing the opposite.  The closest you have is `dr(i)`, a DataReader item is `Object` and an implied ToString should work fine.  Do be sure Option Strict is on

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You don't need the `Conn.Close()` and `Conn.Dispose()` because you have `Conn` in a `Using` block. And you _should_ have `sw` in a `Using` block as well, in which case you would not need `sw.Close()` and `sw.Dispose()`.

Comment: The error occurs at line sb.Append(dr(i))   With the error:                    An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Here is the stack on it, still having the issue, and this is occuring at the sb.Append(dr(i) + sep) portion : System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number,

Answer (score 2):

Most likely culprit is the line

```
sb.Append(dr(i) + sep)
```

VB uses `&` operator to concatenate strings, try replacing it with

```
sb.Append(dr(i) & sep)
```

Or better yet use different logic, instead of

```
If i <> fields Then
  sep = ","
Else
  sep = ""
End If
sb.Append(dr(i) + sep)
```

do something like

```
sb.Append(dr(i))
If i <> fields Then sb.Append(",")
```

**EDIT:** Added check for possible Null values:

```
If dr(i) Is DbNull.Value OrElse dr(i) Is Nothing Then
    sb.Append("[No Data]")
Else
    sb.Append(dr(i))
End If
```

Comment: I made these adjustments and am still getting the same error. I have posted above what debugging brought up

Comment: @JefforyDampier *The error occurs at line sb.Append(dr(i))* - verify what the value of `dr(i)` is at the time of the error. You may have to add some validation to account for null values

Comment: The value looks to be a double at the time. Do you have any suggestions for validating of a null value that I can try?

Comment: @JefforyDampier added basic check to my answer, see the edit.

Comment: After adding this validation, the error is now coming up on:                                  If dr(i) Is DBNull.Value OrElse dr(i) Is Nothing Then
When looking at the error message it seems to be trying to convert a string to a number?

Comment: Very weird. What happens if instead of `dr(i)` you try `dr.GetString(i)` ?

Comment: It gives me a "cannot cast" error for an integer value that is trying to be converted.